# Start animation if passed 5 seconds

Tags: java, android, timer

How can i check if 5 seconds has passed in Java (Android).

```
if (passedTime >= 5) {
    startAnimation();
} else {
    Log.d("TAG", passedTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.nanoTime()` for this purpose to measure the time elapsed.

For example, you could do:

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
while (System.nanoTime() - start < 5000000);
StartAnimation();
```

or, if its not the main Thread and the Thread has no other purpose than starting the Animation:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    startAnimation();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
     // handle Interruption Exception here
}
```

Also, if the thread is doing some other stuff, you can do (but it will be not percisely 5 seconds);

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
bool doStuff = true;
while (doStuff) {
    if (System.nanoTime() - start >= 5000000) {
        StartAnimation();
    }
    // Do other stuff here
}
```

of you start an own thread that will start the animation (probably the best solution in my opinion):

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            // Make sure animation will run on UI Thread!
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    StartAnimation();
                }
            });
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Handle exception
        }

    }
}).start();
```

EDIT:

After reading your last comment:
I would pass that logic to startAnimation:

```
// Class variable:
long lastAnimationStart = 0;

void StartAnimation() {
    if (lastAnimationStart = 0 || System.nanoTime() - lastAnimationStart >= 5000000) {
        lastAnimationStart = System.nanoTime();
        // Animation stuff here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Handler and post delayed messages to it. Something like this:

```
private static final int MSG_START_ANIMATION = 1337;
private Handler mAnimationHandler = new Handler() {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case MSG_START_ANIMATION:
                startAnimation();
                break;
        }
    }
};
private final ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener mOnPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mAnimationHandler.removeMessages(MSG_START_ANIMATION);
        mAnimationHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MSG_START_ANIMATION, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
};
```

Also, read this blog post about leaking a context through inner Handler classes: [Android Design Patterns](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html)